# CHEF >> rails command , cookbook, recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am having trouble with cookbook and rails...
so this is my latest code...I already installed ruby...

on my cookbook,

```
bash "rails" do
 user "root"
 code <<-EOH gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc" EOH
end

bash "create myapp dir" do
 code <<-EOH
 rails new myapp
 EOH
end
```

help rails new myapp isnt working!

Comment: infos :: I can "rails new foo" on the server itself manually using vagrant ssh... but through cookbook recipe it wont work

Comment: anyone? Im a newbie and I really need it. TIA :)

Comment: What error message do you recieve when applying the recipe?

Comment: I found out that on using Chef recipe,, you need to indicate where. using the cwd or other codes :)

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion.. I'll post the answer anyway as there's some extra notes in there.

Comment: yes thank you sir. but it took me hours before i realize :) but it's all okay now! thanks! @mtm

Answer (score 0):

Try and look for a Chef [resource](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html) or custom cookbook for doing things wherever possible. It will make life easier than trying to write `bash` scripts or your own cookbooks to do everything.

You can use [`gem_package`](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_gem_package.html) to install the `rails` gem to the default system ruby:

```
gem_package "rails" do
  options   "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  action    :install
end
```

When you do need to use [the `bash` resource](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_bash.html) you usually need to tell it what directory to work in with `cwd`

```
myapp = "thisapp"
bash "create #{myapp} dir" do
  cwd   "/your/app/path/#{myapp}"
  code  "rails new #{myapp}"
end
```

Comment: thanks sir this will be a big help, especially to other newbies